# Word specific search in asp using c# for auto-complete

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a column in sql called "Name", it has these values:

```
abhay kumar
rajesh saaw
anjan raj
gopal murti
pravat saha
```

Now I want sql code that will return only words containing "r".

So in this query, it should return:

```
kumar, rajesh, raj, murti, pravat
```

and **not**:

```
abhay, anjan, gopal, saha.
```

Answer (score 2):

The SQL [`LIKE` operator](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) should do the job. You can compare against text pattern using the following SQL command form:

```
SELECT ... WHERE Name LIKE '%r%';
```

For example:

```
SELECT Name FROM Person WHERE Name LIKE '%r%';
```

The `%` is a wildcard that represents various count of various characters (similarly to `*` in filenames). So `%r%` means any string that contains the letter `r`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are connecting to your data in C#, but if you are using linq, I'd recommend the following (although I'm making a lot of assumptions regarding your data access layer):

```
ctx.User.All(u => u.Contains("r"));
```

Comment: Don't forget, you may want to consider case ignorance too